# Efficient data structures for disjoint integer intervals

Tags: data-structures, hash, intervals

I have a set of disjoint integer intervals and want to check whether a given integer lies in one of these intervals. Of course, this can be achieved by means of a binary search in logarithmic time. However, the vast majority of the queries return `false`, i.e., only very few integers lie in any interval. To speedup the application, I'm looking for a probabilistic, *constant-time* algorithm (some sort of hash function) that tells me whether a given integer is definitely not or maybe in an interval. Here is a sketch of the intended algorithm, where `magic_data_structure` is initialized with the intervals stored in `tree`:

```
x = some_integer;
if(!magic_data_structure.find(x))
  return false; // definitely not in any interval
return tree.find(x); // binary search on tree
```

Any ideas or hints for literature? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

P.S.: Does anybody know improvements of interval trees for *non-overlapping* intervals which (unlike the ones described above) may include other intervals?

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive solution, but constant.

If you are not dealing with extremely large quantities of numbers, you could just use a hash table where the keys are the numbers and the values are a pointer to the set they're in.  But of course if there is a lot of data it might take too long (and too much memory) to index it this way.

Looks like there are various [disjoint-set data structures and algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to store/search them, but I doubt if any of them have constant times.